# Heads-up уведомления на устройствах с версиями Android 8+

Tags: android, уведомления

Тестировал отправку уведомлений с высоким приоритетом и звуком. На эмуляторах и железках с версией Android ниже 8 все OK - выезжает сверху со звуком. На эмуляторах с версиями 8+ уведомление выезжает без звука. На железке Redmi Note 7   с Android P не выезжает сверху, а беззвучно появляется на панели уведомлений. Подскажите в чем проблема.

```
package com.example.notificationtest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 public static final String CH_ID = "channelId";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onShowClick(View view) {
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CH_ID)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_active_black_24dp)
            .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +
                    getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bike_bell))
            .build();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CH_ID, "channelName",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);


        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    manager.notify(777, notification);


}
```

}

Comment: каждое устройство может вести себя по разному. Плюс пользователь может отключить ваше приложение на получение уведомлений